# Using Java, how to verify/validate Google Analytics Asynchronus Tracking Code(Analytics snippet ) is under the <head> tag section of a webpage source

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, google-analytics

Here is the example of the Analytics snippet to be verified that it is a part of head section of a web page source code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gag = _gag || [];
   _gag.push(['_setAccount','UA-XXXX-X']);  
   _gag.push(['_trackPageView']);   

    setTimeout(function(){
        var ga = document.createElement('script');ga.type ="text/javascript"; ga.sync = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http//www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var ga = document.getElementsByTagName9'script')[0];
        s.parentnode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need to verify that the above Analytics code snippet is under the <head> tag of a web page source code. Here is the reference link that I used          http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/02/09/where-put-google-tracking-code/

Comment: Verify programatically? Manually? Why do you need to verify this?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Need to verify programatically using Selenium with Java.  Has such requirement.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks Halcyon for you time. Basically Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you use selenium webdriver than you can search all script tags in the and iterate over the list to find the matching script name page by :

```
List<WebElement> scriptList = webDriver.findElements(By.tagName("script"))
boolean scriptFound = false;
for(WebElement item : scriptList){
    scriptFound = item.getAttribute("src").contains("google-analytics.com/ga.js");
}
 if(!scriptFound) {}//fail the test
```

Comment: Don't really know much about Selenium - does this parse Javascript (the script tag is generated dynamically by the GA bootstrap code), and could it possibly be extended to to listen for the http  request (so one can be sure GA ist actually working) ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Selenium is all about finding elements in the dom based on xpath or css selector, by id or by name, and even if this is added dynamically, in the end this script content/source or any other specific detail can be retrieved for further identification.Configured for http request - don't think so. And I don't see any reason why would you do testing of a third party library functionality?

Comment: Because knowing the tracking library is there might not be enough, maybe you want to  test automatically  if the thing actually works. There is much room for a broken GA implementation even if the tracking library is present.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Well the question was how to identify the script, but not how to implement a testing mechanism for it's functionality. May be it is possible, but I didn't think of such test case - thus I don't know if it can or can't be done with selenium. I would assume that you want to intercept the request that comes from the ui to the application back-end -> for such interceptor the test code should run on the same web server, which is not the case of how selenium works.